# Recreate "Voltage gain vs Frequency" graph of Op-Amp in LT Spice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, gain, bode-plot

I am trying to recreate the "Voltage gain vs Frequency" graph of the LT1037 Op-Amp in LT Spice. According to the [datasheet page 6](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1007-LT1037.pdf) the graph looks like this: -

[image]

Trying to recreate this in LT Spice gives me a graph, that doesn't match the graph above: -

[image]

As you can see, the gain is not as high, and graph starts to roll off at a higher frequency. I would like to know why the two graphs doesn't match at all. I believe it has something to do with the resistor values, but I have a feeling that I'm missing some key understanding - such as a wrong circuit design.

Comment: The nominal gain at DC from the datasheet is about 18 *million*. Your ac input needs to be very small to see that gain within the limits of the output voltage swing.

Comment: Your circuit is not running open-loop; it has negative feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determination of the open-loop gain of an op-amp in a SPICE simulator can be done in various ways. However, in any case, to reveal the ac response, you need to maintain adequate bias on the output to prevent the op-amp from railing up or down. For instance, if you have a 12-V supply, you may want to maintain the output at 6 V so that enough dynamics exists on the output (no risks of saturation) when ac-modulating the circuit. Assume a large open-loop gain, e.g. 120 dB, then it translates to \$10^6\$ which implies a dc bias precisely tweaked at the µV level.

Another approach is to include the op-amp whose frequency response is needed within an external self-biasing circuit which automatically adjusts the dc bias to match the 6-V (or any other value) you want. The circuit is rather simple here with a LM358:

[image]

When you launch a SPICE simulation, whether it is an AC or TRAN analysis, the engine always starts by a bias point calculation to determine where to run the linearization of all nonlinear elements. Dc analysis is done by opening all capacitors and shorting all inductors. In the proposed circuit, the inductor LoL is replaced by a short while CoL is open-circuited. The voltage-controlled voltage-source then adjusts its output and biases the op-amp to have it deliver the voltage set by \$V_4\$ which is 6 V in this example: the circuit operates in closed-loop. Then, when the ac analysis starts, LoL and CoL form a low-pass filter and block any modulation, making the circuit run in open-loop in ac. If you plot the op-amp output in this mode, you obtain its open-loop gain as wanted:

[image]

This LoL-CoL trick is extensively used for opening the loop with averaged models for switching converters. What is cool with this circuit is that if you change the supply, the loading conditions or the op-amp sub-circuit, the auto-bias circuit automatically tweaks the bias to maintain the output within the selected output voltage range.

Comment: Thank you for your good and inspiring answer, as always.

Comment: With pleasure! : )

Answer (score 3):

Well - here is the explanation for the unexpected behaviour.

1. You are not simulating open-loop but with feedback. I suppose that you are aware of this. For open-loop simulation you must take some actions to ensure a correct bias point within the linear amplification range
2. More interesting: What happens when the frequency is increasing up to pretty large values? The gain of the opamp decreases and with it the loop gain of the whole circuit. More than that, the inverting input node cannot longer be regarded as "virtual ground". And now the output resistance r_out of the opamp comes into the play. Due to the loop gain drop the output resistance is increasing and an unwanted portion of the input signal (which arrives DIRECTLY via R2 at the output node) causes an unwanted output voltage across r-out. That is the primary reason for the observed behaviour.

**Correction:**  My answer above is - in principle - correct and the described effect does exist. However, the result of the mentioned "direct coupling effect" is not the primary cause of the observed behaviour. I have performed a simulation by myself under open-loop conditions - and the result is as follows:

The gain and phase enhancement in the region at app. 1 MHz is caused by a kind of internal frequency compensation which ensures stability even in case of unity feedback (most critical situation). Perhaps this frequency compensation in the used opamp model (from LT) is somewhat "stronger" than in the real device (more gain-phase enhancement).
However, such open-loop gain responses as shown in data books should be always regarded as "typical" only. For example, the shown maximum gain of nearly 150 dB will certainly has an uncertainty (tolerance) of 10 dB or so....